# After adding image to header title header left back button not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am sharing my app.js file and I have a problem when I pressed headerleft back button it donot work and not navigating to prev. screen (It appears as disabled button).
React native navigation V6

```
import { StyleSheet,StatusBar,Platform,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import OnBoarding from './app/screens/OnBoarding';
import LoginScreen from './app/screens/loginScreen';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Register from './app/screens/register'
import OtpScreen from './app/screens/OtpScreen';
import HomeScreen from './app/screens/HomeScreen';
import ForgetPasswordScreen from './app/screens/ForgetPasswordScreen';
import WelcomeScreen from './app/screens/WelcomeScreen';
import Profile from './app/screens/Profile';
import ResetPassword from './app/screens/ResetPassword';
import ExamPage from './app/screens/Pages/Services/ExamPage';
import ExamScreen from './app/screens/ExamScreen';
import G1Description from './app/screens/Pages/Services/G1Descriptions';
import Colors from './app/config/Colors';
import HeaderImage from './app/component/HeaderImage/HeaderImage'
import SplashScreen from './app/screens/SplashScreen';
import {Ionicons} from '@expo/vector-icons'


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  const StackNavigator = ()=>(
    <Stack.Navigator screenOption={{headerStyle:{backgroundColor:Colors.primary}}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="OnBoarding" component={OnBoarding}
        options = {{
                headerShown:false
              }} 
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen"  
      options = {{
                headerShown:false
              }} component={LoginScreen}/>

      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register}
        options = {{
                headerShown:false
              }} 
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="ResetPassword" component={ResetPassword}
        options = {{
                headerShown:false
              }} 
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="OtpScreen" component={OtpScreen}
        options = {{
                headerShown:false
              }} 
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen"  component={HomeScreen} 
        options = {{
                headerTintColor:Colors.white,
                headerStyle:{backgroundColor:Colors.primary},
                headerTitleStyle:{textAlign: 'center' },headerBackTitleVisible:false,
                headerTitle:(props)=><HeaderImage {...props}/>
                }}/> 
      <Stack.Screen name="ForgetPasswordScreen" component={ForgetPasswordScreen}
        options = {{
                headerShown:false
              }} 
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile}/>     
      <Stack.Screen name="ExamScreen" component={ExamScreen} 
        options = {{
                headerTintColor:Colors.white,
                headerStyle:{backgroundColor:Colors.primary},
                headerTitleStyle:{textAlign: 'center' },
                headerTitle:(props)=><HeaderImage {...props}/>}}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="ExamPage" component={ExamPage} 
        options = {{
                headerTintColor:Colors.white,
                headerStyle:{backgroundColor:Colors.primary},
                headerTitleStyle:{textAlign: 'center',position:'absolute' },headerBackTitleVisible:false,
                headerTitle:(props)=><HeaderImage {...props}/>,
                
                }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="G1Description" component={G1Description} 
        options = {{
                  headerTintColor:Colors.white,                
                  headerStyle:{backgroundColor:Colors.primary},
                  headerTitleStyle:{textAlign: 'center' },headerBackTitleVisible:false,
                  headerTitle:(props)=><HeaderImage {...props}/>
                }}

                />

    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
export default function App() {  

 
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StackNavigator/>
    </NavigationContainer>
    // {/* <SplashScreen/> */}
 
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop:30,    
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

try: When I stopped showing header Title Image. I works properly fine.
expectation: To start work with back button along with header Title.